# Set background colour on tab characters in a pre element

Tags: html, css

How can I get the background colour of a tab character to cover the full line height of a containing pre element without breaking tabstops?

It is for syntax highlighting code.
I don't want to convert tabs to spaces or use javaScript.

https://jsfiddle.net/qftvv9dp/

```
pre.tab4 {
  tab-size: 4;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 18pt;
  background-color: #DDDDFF;
}

span.goodTabBadBack {
  background-color: green;
}

span.badTabGoodBack {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.goodTabGoodBack {
  background-color: red;
  /* What to put? */
}

<pre class='tab4'>
0123456789abcdef
0   4<span class="goodTabBadBack">  </span>8    c
0   45<span class="goodTabBadBack"> </span>89   c
0   456<span class="goodTabBadBack">    </span>890  c
</pre>

<pre class='tab4'>
0123456789abcdef
0   4<span class="badTabGoodBack">  </span>8    c
0   45<span class="badTabGoodBack"> </span>89   c
0   456<span class="badTabGoodBack">    </span>890  c
</pre>

<pre class='tab4'>
0123456789abcdef
0   4<span class="goodTabGoodBack"> </span>8    c
0   45<span class="goodTabGoodBack">    </span>89   c
0   456<span class="goodTabGoodBack">   </span>890  c
</pre>
```

Comment: One way is to put a padding on the span.See [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qftvv9dp/1/). Not posting this as an answer, since it's a bit patchy; I had to calculate the amount of padding manually and it depends on the font, the font size, the browser etc. It will probably need to be different for each particular situation. But you may be able to use this as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah, hard coding padding is not ideal. I guess it's not so simple.